como quitar candado azules en C# y recuperar formularios
buenos días me gustaría saber is me puedes ayudar, estaba trabajando en un código y agregue un recurso al mismo pero al usarlo no lo pintaba en el formulario, asi que lo elimine pero al hacerlo me cerro el formulario y no pude abrirlo mas cuando ejecute me apareció error y no me dio la opción de ingresa al designer para eliminar la linea de codigo de la imagen, cometí el error de omitir y continuar y ahora no me abren dos de los formularios iniciales y aparecen unos vistos rojos y candados azules en el código no se como recuperar los formularios  y que intente rehacerlos porque aparecen en blanco pero al hacerlo me arroja error por que ya están y en el código efectivamente aparece toda la información pero gráficamente no la muestra

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! segurametne te esta tirando errores.. podrias mostrarlos?? a veces no queda otra que trabajar esos errores por fuera de la ide... algo se rompio, tenes que arreglarlo a mano...
